# React Native Redux getState() always 0

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have been following some React Redux tutorials so decided to try and implement one of the examples:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = createStore(this.counter);
  }

  counter(state = 0, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'INCREMENT':
        return state + 1;
      break;
      case 'DECREMENT':
        return state - 1;
      break;
      default:
        return state;
      break
    }
  }

  increment() {
    this.store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.store.getState()}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.increment()}>
          <Text>INCREMENT</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If I `console.log` the value of `state` in `counter` I can see it changing. However, when I do `this.store.getState()` within the `render` method, it stays at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Home component's props and state aren't changing, it isn't re-rendering, which is why you're not seeing the Redux store's state update in the render method.

A more common approach to implementing Redux with React is to use [react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux) to connect container components to specific parts of your Redux state as props, that way the component will always re-render correctly because its props change as the Redux state changes.